# How do i use on mail function line to send all email and messages in record

Tags: php, string, email

I have this code:

```
<?php
$emails = 'email1@example.com,email2@example.com';
$emailsSplitted = explode(',', $emails);

foreach ($emailsSplitted as $email) {
    $to ='$email';
    $message = 'send this to all email above';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $headers = 'From: multiplememail@gm.Com';
    mail($to, $subject,$message, $headers);
}
$str = "abc@email.com[thanks]wap@email.com[i want also]data@email.com[multiple msg]";
$regExpresion = "/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/";

preg_match_all($regExpresion, $str, $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($aMatches as $aMail){
    $to = $aMail[1];
    $message = $aMail[2];
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $headers = 'From: multiple@gm.Com';
    mail($to, $subject,$message, $headers);
}
$to = 'abc@email.com';
$message = 'single message';
$subject = 'the subject';
$headers = 'From: singleemail@gm.Com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

which send email line by line just as is it in my code above but am sorry, just want to know if i can use just one mail function line to deliver this than doing it for each string record. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use 'n comma delimited string of emails

Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Simply pass in the $emails variable to the mail() function as the first parameter.

so it would be:

```
$emails = 'email1@example.com,email2@example.com';

$message = 'send this to all email above';
$subject = 'the subject';
$headers = 'From: multiplememail@gm.Com';

mail($emails, $subject,$message, $headers);
```

Comment: not what i want see e:g

$emails = 'email1@example.com,email2@example.com';
 $emailsSplitted = explode(',', $emails);
foreach ($emailsSplitted as $email) {
$to = '$email';
$message 'yes i want';
$str = "abc@email.com[thanks]wap@email.com[i want also]data@email.com[multiple msg]";
$regExpresion = "/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/";    
preg_match_all($regExpresion, $str, $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($aMatches as $aMail)
 {
 $to = $aMail[1];
   $message = $aMail[2];
$subject = 'the subject';
 $headers = 'From: stringemail@gm.Com';
   mail($to, $subject,
 $message, $headers);
}
}